# ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))

Tags: python, twine

everybody! I have a python package in [PyPI](https://pypi.org/), i went to update it. but the upload command not executed correctly!

command:

```
twine upload dist/*
```

error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

os: linux mint,
python: 3.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely to the fact that PYPI is migrating from pypi.python.org to pypi.org

User migration instructions can be found [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/). Alternatively you can try "legacy" approach:

```
python setup.py clean build sdist upload --repository=https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Comment: Your code was very useful and I used it. In addition, I updated the `~ /.pypirc` file. [link](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues/590#issuecomment-316972088)