# Broken Pipe Error when uploading to pypi with Twine

Tags: python, conda, twine

Same error as [ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880536/connectionerror-connection-aborted-brokenpipeerror32-broken-pipe) except that my exact error message is

```
File "/anaconda3/envs/chihack/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 320, in _send_until_done
    return self.connection.send(data)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/chihack/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1737, in send
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/chihack/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1639, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (32, 'EPIPE')
```

Command run is `twine upload --repository-url https://pypi.org/project/<project_name> dist/*`

All the discussions I have found relating to this error have not been related to twine, and none of the solutions have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

The command should be `twine upload dist/*`.

Comment: I also was trying to include the repository url in the command and removing it this way fixed it. If you have multiple dists, you'll want to do `twine upload dist/<the dist version you want>.tar.gz`